# Question with newer duplicates is closed

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, close-reasons

I read a meta post on the horrors of the close queue, so I immediately started reviewing. I got this question: [Best approach to multi-part int dictionary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4974509/1087848). It has three close-votes because it is a duplicate. Because it *is* a duplicate. The only thing is, that question is a duplicate of two **newer** questions. (The question I linked to is 3 years old, the duplicates only a few months.) In other words, there are duplicates *of* this question.

To close the oldest question would be unfair to the author of that question, because having closed questions looks bad. (Having too much closed questions can even get you a penalty, but I don't think that is applicable here. The question shows effort and is well phrased.)

It already has three close votes, so I don't think reversing it is possible, but just closing it doesn't seem right either. What do I do?

Comment: Close the duplicates as a duplicate of the best question and answers. We want people to find information.

Comment: While that question refers to the quality of a question, I am referring to the age of the question. I do not think those are duplicates. But then, most of my meta a posts are downvoted/closed.

Comment: someone went thru and flagged a bunch of 'multi dictionary key` questions recently.  I had about 8 in a row in the dupe queue today.  someone maybe wrote an answer and then want to redirect old posts to it.

Comment: Unless there are competing duplicate votes that I can't see (there is only 1 possible duplicate comment), the example you provided doesn't match the description.  The proposed duplicate is from 2009 whereas the question you referenced is from 2011.

Comment: Hm. Strange. Maybe I saw the 'last activity' date. But even without the example, the question is still valid. @psubsee2003

Comment: @11684 yes, it is valid as valid question, just pointing it out.  But I disagree that age is a factor.  Duplicate closing is not a punishment.  It just points other users to the best answers, so if the best answer is on a newer question then it closing the older question as a duplicate of the newer one is the right choice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whatever question/answer pair is of the highest quality, and has the most value to future readers who have this problem are is the question that should be open.  Any duplicate questions, regardless of when they were asked, should be closed as duplicates of *the best question*.

Closing a question with a great answer as a duplicate of a question with a poor answer, just because of when they were asked, is not being helpful to the community.

The date of the question/answer is simply irrelevant when considering whether a post is a duplicate, or which of several duplicate questions should be the one left open.